# How can I reference the current class as a return type in YARD?

Tags: ruby, yard

Consider a code like this:

```rb
module Foo
  # returns a copy of self
  # @return [ ___ ]
  def returns_new_self
    self.class.new
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end

class Zap
  include Foo
end
```

With this, `Bar.new.returns_new_self` will return another `Bar`, and the same goes with `Zap.new.returns_new_self`.

I want to have `retuns_new_self` YARD-documented with a return type.
It will be nice if I could do something like `@return [Self]` as the `Self` in Rust.

Can I do something similar?

---

EDIT: (in reply to @spickermann)

The actual code is like this:

```rb
module MultipleItemBehaviour
  # @return [Integer]
  def count; not_implemented end

  # @return [Enumerator]
  def each_count
    return enum_for(:each_count) unless block_given?

    count.times do
      yield single_item
    end
  end

  # @return [ __SELF__ ]
  def single_item; not_implemented end

  private def not_implemented
    raise NotImplementedError, "message"
  end
end

class SomeItemWhichIsABunch
  include MultipleItemBehaviour

  attr_reader :count
  def initialize(count)
    @count = count
  end

  def single_item
    self.class.new(1)
  end
end

SomeItemWhichIsABunch.each_count.take(5).map(&:something)
```

I understand this is a bit off from OOP (it's better to split that Item to a Container and the concrete Items),
but since it's a bunch of all the same things, and it's the way it is stored in the DB already, I decided I want to return a enumerator like this.

---

EDIT 2:
I am passing the `--embed-mixin` option to yard. The current result in the includer Class document is like this: (sorry for the different module name)
[image: The details part of <code>Bar</code>]

Comment: Does YARD actually generate docs for included methods in the including module? I only know that _"Methods included from …"_ section which merely contains links to those methods.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you want to have a dedicated method for that? IMO `foo.class.new` is shorter and easier to understand than `foo.returns_new_self`?

Comment: @Stefan When you pass (or put in yardopts) the `--embed-mixin` option, the `included` methods would be listed in the document with information from the tags and strings.

Comment: @spickermann: This was just a short example, but I am trying to create a way to return lists of itself.. Please see the EDIT for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, YARD can't do that. The best alternative is being explicit in your `Foo#returns_new_self` documentation. Personally, I'd be totally fine with something along the lines of

```rb
module Foo
  ##
  # Returns a new instance of the object's class.
  #
  # @return [Object]
  def returns_new_self
    self.class.new
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end

class Zap
  include Foo
end
```

Which yields the following doc:

[image: foo documentation]
[image: bar documentation]

Comment: You seem right..., So because we don't have a `Self` of `__CLASS__` or something like that (or not if I implement some plugin for that), documenting in words may be the best options for now after all?

Comment: Yeah, and I think it's pretty clean, tbh. However, the use case you want is interesting; you might want to submit a feature request or see if such a feature request already exists.

Answer (score 1):

yardoc does not generate documentation in the way you're describing.

When you generate the documentation, `Bar` and `Zap` will have a section that says:

> Methods included from `Foo`
>
> `#returns_new_self`

`#returns_new_self` will link to the documentation for `Foo`, and the documentation for `Foo` will state the possible return types for that method. The individual classes will not have documentation for that method.

You can still document `returns_new_self` inside of `Foo`. Setting the return type to any of the following would be considered valid:

A hard-coded list of values from classes that include the module:

```
# @return [Bar,Zap]
```

A superclass of the classes that include the module:

```
# @return [Object]
```

The [literal](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#Literals) `void` for an undefined return type:

```
# @return [void]
```

Comment: `self` would be misleading here. It is used to mean that the method returns the object itself, i.e. the same instance. This is useful to indicate that a method is chainable (in a DSL, for example). It should not be used to indicate that a method returns a different instance of the same class. I'd be confused if I saw this method return `self` in the documentation.

Comment: You can pass the `--embed-mixin` option to yard, which outputs `#count ⇒ Integer (also: #amount) included from Foo` in the document for `Bar` (sorry for the lack of screenshots), and I wanted to have that section point to the current `Bar` automatically..